# Looping through hidden fields

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how i would loop through hidden fields with jquery to get their values. The hidden fields are in a php while loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input:hidden').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    // do something with the value
});
```

Comment: this also returns any element that has `dispaly:none` within its style

Comment: @RobertPitt, I wonder why would someone use a `display:none` style on a hidden field :-)

Comment: you point would be valid if your using `input:hidden` but as your just using `:hidden` your select all types of elements such as `span`,`a`,`div` etc that have `dispaly:none` set to that element, therefore your code could possibly return elements that are not `input`, please see my answer.

Comment: @RobertPitt, you are absolutely correct. I didn't realize my mistake initially. I've updated my answer. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't mather the hidden fields are created in a php loop.

You can loop like this:

```
$("input[type='hidden']").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ..

```
$('input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
 var hiddenValue = $(this).val();  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $('input[type=hidden]').each(function()
  {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

This will make sure the loop is being made only after the document is ready (assuming you don't trigger the loop with a click.
You can also do:

```
function LoopingThrough()
{
  $('input[type=hidden]').each(function()
  {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
  });
}
```

In case no you don't understand the different between .val() and .attr('value') it's this:
when doing .attr('value') jQuery searches for the 'value' attribute in the element.
If you're going through a drop down list, the element wont have a value attribute.
.val() on the other hand already knows how to handle elements that has a value, but don't have the 'value' attribute.

[My Development Blog](http://www.devaffair.com/)

Answer (score -1):

as simply as:

```
$("input[type='hidden']").each(function(index){
    //Work here with this.
})
```

or you can just use the pseudo selector as stated by several other's

```
$(":hidden").each(function(index){
    //Work here with this.
})
```

but the above would also find any element that has `display:none` regardless of its type, some other factors of using `:hidden` are:

- They have a CSS display value of none.
- They are form elements with type="hidden".
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

if you wish to get the value of the input then you can just use

```
var Value = $(this).attr("value");
```

or

```
var Value = $(this).val();
```

Comment: Better use `.val()` instead of `.attr("value")`;

Comment: what difference would this make ?